# Terraform - aws_security_group_rule doesn't support import

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm having a strange problem when trying to import an `aws_security_group_rule` into terraform.

I'm running the latest version of TF (0.11.11)

For example:

`terraform import module.ec2.aws_security_group_rule.control_elb sg-securitygroupid_ingress_tcp_8080_8080_sg-sourcesgid`

Returns `resource aws_security_group_rule doesn't support import`

However, looking at the documentation, this does seem possible?

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group_rule.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to import in flat setup than modular setup? It seems that in modular setup there is a bug with Terraform. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/559